# Cutting letters from alphanumeric cell entry, pasting to another cell

Tags: excel, vba

How can I set up a macro that will strip the letters from #####XX in column I and put them in to column L same row? Thanks!

Comment: Are the letters that need to be removed always the last 2 characters?

Comment: and do you need `vba`. A formula will (most likely) do the job quite well :). For example, in cell `L1` write `=Left(I1,Len(I1)-2)` to show all but the last two letters of cell `I1`. You can also use `Right` and `Mid` to assist if needed.

Comment: Yes, it's always the last two letters. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with the first sheet and you're always stripping off the last two characters while leaving the first 5 characters, the following code will work:

```
Public Sub StripOff()
  Dim iRow as Integer
  iRow = 2       'Assuming row 1 is headers, else make this 1
  While Sheets(1).Range("I" + Cstr(iRow)).Value <> ""
    Sheets(1).Range("L" + CStr(iRow)).Value = Right(Sheets(1).Range("I" + Cstr(iRow)).Value, 2)
    Sheets(1).Range("I" + Cstr(iRow)).Value = Left(Sheets(1).Range("I" + Cstr(iRow)).Value, 5)
    iRow = iRow + 1
  Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The operative words I'm understanding from your question are **Cutting** and **strip**. To my mind, this means that the last two letters are permanently removed from column I and placed in column L.

```
Sub cut2right()
    Dim v As Long, vPFXS As Variant, vSFXS As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet6")
        vPFXS = .Range(.Cells(2, "I"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))
        ReDim vSFXS(1 To UBound(vPFXS), 1 To 1)
        For v = LBound(vPFXS, 1) To UBound(vPFXS, 1)
            If Len(vPFXS(v, 1)) > 1 Then
                vSFXS(v, 1) = Right(vPFXS(v, 1), 2)
                vPFXS(v, 1) = Left(vPFXS(v, 1), Len(vPFXS(v, 1)) - 2)
            End If
        Next v
        .Cells(2, "I").Resize(UBound(vPFXS, 1), 1) = vPFXS
        .Cells(2, "L").Resize(UBound(vPFXS, 1), 1) = vSFXS
    End With
End Sub
```

Working with variant arrays should speed up working with many cells with variable length string values. If they were all the same length then manually running a Text-to-Columns command with a fixed length to an unused column and then copying and pasting the results to the appropriate column would have done just fine.

Comment: I am getting a "Subscript out of range" error message on this one.

Comment: You would be correct! I got it to run, but nothing happens in the cells with ####XX. The cells that have #### it does pull the last two numbers.

Comment: Have a look at the sample workbook [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Samples/cut2right.xlsb). It must have something to do with your data but I cannot reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the leading numeric characters from a string using the VBA Val function.  To use this function on a worksheet you will need to create a User Defined Function (UDF) in a standard VBA module.

```
Function LeadingNumbers(Str As String) As Double
    LeadingNumbers = Val(Str)
End Function
```

Simply enter the function in a cell and reference the cell containing the string you want "cleaned".